# Django query find whether a column has None value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have the following columns as name and tag in the Content table.

From the following django query is there any way to find the tag named column has `None` values in it without using the for loop without using the .exclude()

```
  newobj = Content.objects.filter(name="Harry")
  boolval = if tag has or not not None value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use __isnull[0]

```
Content.objects.filter(name="Harry", tag__isnull=True)
```

[0] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull

Expanding on this:

> cant we do this from the newobj – Rajeev

.filter() returns a queryset.

```
newobj = Content.objects.filter(name="Harry")
boolval = newobj.exists(tag__isnull=True)
```

This will return true/false (by exists) if there is Harry with null tags.

Comment: cant we do this from the newobj

Comment: Check the expanded version. I hope I understood your comment correctly.